# JAXB 2.x and Ant

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using **JAXB 2.1.2** with the **MOXy** implementation.
To build my web app I am using **Ant 1.7.1** and I am also using the

```
package-info.java
```

class to specify namespace stuff.

All runs fine, except the package-info.java does not get compiled.
in the build directory, there is no expected package-info.class at the dedicated directory (with my domain classes).

How can I force Ant to also compile the package-info.java class?

I read about Ant's limitation here but I can't believe that this has not been resolved?
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Thanks

Comment: I am currently investigating the following "trick": as of the javac limitation in ant, it only compiles the package-info if the java file is newer than the target directory where the class file gets copied to. I now try to do a <touch> with ANT right before the compile, maybe that helps.

Comment: However, I wonder how other projects to solve this issue when they have to use the package-info.java (e.g. MOXy uses that file to declare namespace prefix values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found a workaround myself, so this works fine but only if you compile twice (somehow the target folder where the class file gets stored to must be older than the package-info.java file):
Instead of these ant commands in my build.xml:

```
<mkdir dir="${realm.classes.dir}"/>
<javac srcdir="${realm.java.dir}" destdir="${realm.classes.dir}"
  classpathref="classpath"
  encoding="${javac.encoding}"
  debug="true"
/>
```

I had to use the additional  command:

```
<mkdir dir="${realm.classes.dir}"/>
<touch>
  <fileset dir="${realm.java.dir}" includes="**/package-info.java"/>
</touch>
<javac srcdir="${realm.java.dir}" destdir="${realm.classes.dir}"
  classpathref="classpath"
  encoding="${javac.encoding}"
  debug="true"
/>
```

If you have a better solution, let me know!

Comment: I'm using ANT 1.8.2 via Jenkins, and the package-info.java are compiled but no package-info.class files are generated. I also tried the mentioned solution but without success, any hint's.

Comment: Did you build it twice? Otherwise the workaround does not work.